# Writing onto HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, regex, angularjs, while-loop

So for a brief context, my program reads in a file and displays it onto the html page. The code below uses a regex expression to read that file and extract the errors. Instead of using console.log each time and debugging, is there any I way I could just write the results onto the HTML page?

When I used:

```
document.getElementById("").innerHTML
```

it would just print out the last summary instead of printing out all of the summaries.

I tried using a controller and ng-repeat (AngularJS) to do it, but somehow I did not do it right.

Any ideas -- doesn't have to be in AngularJS???

```
while ((match = reDiaBtoa.exec(reader.result)) != null) {
    if (match.index === reDiaBtoa.lastIndex) {
        reDiaBtoa.lastIndex++;
    }

    // View your result using the match-variable.
    // eg match[0] etc.
    // extracts the status code: ERROR

    if (match[2] === "ERROR" || match[2] === "FATAL" || match[2] === "SEVERE") {
        console.log("Time: " + match[1]);
        console.log("Thread Name: " + match[3]);
        console.log("Source name & line number: " + match[4]);
        console.log("Log Message: " + match[5] + '\n');
        console.log("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
} //end of the while loop ((match = reDiaBtoa.exec.....))
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the code that you tried with angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use

`document.getElementById("someId").innerHTML =`

it'll overwrite the existing html.

instead, use

`document.getElementById("someId").innerHTML +=`

Comment: Better yet, append a text node.  Unless the content you're appending is a string of HTML, then `x.innerHTML += ...` is overpowered because HTML can do things that plain text nodes cannot and inefficient because you're asking the HTML parser to rebuild the entire content just to append at end.

Answer (score 0):

Create a string variable before your while loop and then append to it in your loop:

```
var outputToDisplay = "";
//While loop
outputToDisplay += "Time: " + match[1];
//etc

//End While
document.getElementById(theId).innherHTML = outputToDisplay;
```